# Javascript Multidimensional array, data push adding the same data in every row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Objective:
I am creating a system that will pull data from an old website. I am reading the data of each li and and trying to put it in an array so I could convert it in json.

What I tried

Defined 2 array and loop's max limit

```
var valueToPush = new Array();
var cookie_value_add = new Array();
var maxvalue = $("ul.list-inline").length + 1;
```

Running a for loop so I could read all data and assigning all in variables.

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i < maxvalue; i++) {
    var addLine1 = $( "ul#"+i+" li:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(1)" ).text();
    var addLine2 = $( "ul#"+i+" li:nth-child(2) span:nth-child(3)" ).text();
    var teL = $( "ul#"+i+" li:nth-child(3) span:nth-child(1) a" ).attr("href");
    var fistName = $( "ul#"+i+" li:nth-child(4) span:nth-child(1) b" ).text();
    var lastName = $( "ul#"+i+" li:nth-child(4) span:nth-child(2) a" ).text();
```

if I get some value then putting in 2D array

```
    if(teL==null){
        //will do something
    }else{
        // alert('doing');
        // var dataX.push([addLine1, addLine2, teL, fistName, lastName]);
        valueToPush['0'] = addLine1;
        valueToPush['1'] = addLine2;
        valueToPush['2'] = teL;
        valueToPush['3'] = fistName;
        valueToPush['4'] = lastName;

        cookie_value_add.push(valueToPush);
    }
}
```

Trying to see the exact length of Data that is correct

```
alert(cookie_value_add.length);
```

Trying to alert a data that was in 5th row and third value, but it is showing the last row's data, THIS IS THE PROBLEM.

```
alert(cookie_value_add[5]['3']);
```

Trying to covert everything into json, It working but it shows last row is in every row of Json string

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(cookie_value_add);
alert(myJSON);
```

I searched on Internet very much even on stack-overflow but couldn't find everything what I need.
Thank you.

Comment: Re-initialize `valueToPush` to `[]` before filling it with values. As it is, you're overwriting the values in the same array over and over again.

Comment: @Pointy Yes I did as you told, Seems working, Now cross checking.

Comment: @Pointy Yes It worked Thanks.

Comment: To elaborate/clarify: in JS, arrays and objects are copied by reference. So when you assign a variable equal to another which holds an array/object, modifying that object later will reflect those changes in every variable that references it. So you need to create a new array at some point before assigning it / pushing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of declaring it globally you need to again create a new variable set new value and push into array. i think modify this code will help you

```
if(teL==null){
        //will do something
    }else{
        var valueToPush = new Array(); // modified
        valueToPush['0'] = addLine1;
        valueToPush['1'] = addLine2;
        valueToPush['2'] = teL;
        valueToPush['3'] = fistName;
        valueToPush['4'] = lastName;

        cookie_value_add.push(valueToPush);
    }
}
```